# How to dynamically load a vue directive?

Tags: vue.js

For performance issues I want to dynamically load a Vue directive.
But when I try to use the same method as for [the dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) it doesn't work

```
directives: {
    mydirective: () => {
        return import('@/src/directives/mydirective.js');
    }
}
// In a .vue file
```

If someone has already done that with success it could be nice to share.
Thanks

Comment: Reading through the API documentation, it does not seem like it's able to load directives dynamically.

Comment: You can't load directives dynamically. They're typically really small in terms of both code size and resource usage footprint and that it doesn't really make sense to load them dynamically. Feel free to share the contents of your directive, focusing on the part you think affects the performance of your app and someone might be able to come up with a solution for it. From what you've shown so far it doesn't look like you have a real problem.

Comment: Yes indeed, it's not a big code size.. but it was just to avoid to increase my unsed code in my nuxt APP because this directive is used only on one page :)